# What is the easiest way to find out in what file a word is contained?

Tags: linux, unix, bash, command-line-interface

I've got a **number of .conf files** in the following "**lxadmin**" directory and suspect that the text "**tanguay.info**" is in one of them somewhere.

I do this command:

```
cat /etc/httpd/conf/lxadmin/* | grep "tanguay.info"
```

And it tells me:

```
cat: /etc/httpd/conf/lxadmin/forward: Is a directory
Include /home/httpd/tanguay.info/conf/lxadmin.tanguay.info
```

So I know that it is in there **somewhere**, but it doesn't tell me **in which file**.

**How can I get it to also tell me in which file the text is located?**

Comment: This is a classic useless usage of cat. In 99% of cases you do not need to use cat, as the command you're piping to will take a filename or a list of files. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html will show you some examples of how to write your commands better.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

grep "tanguay.info" /etc/httpd/conf/lxadmin/*, as long as the file is not in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 14):

If there are subdirectories you can use

```
rgrep "tanguay.info" /etc/httpd/conf/lxadmin/
```

or

```
grep -r "tanguay.info" /etc/httpd/conf/lxadmin/
```

**EDIT:**

You can also use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/), an enhanced grep written in perl (no deps
required on standalone version). ack searches recursively through 
directories by default.

```
ack "tanguay.info" /etc/httpd/conf/lxadmin/
```

On Ubuntu, you can find it in the ack-grep package.

Comment: If grep is given more than one file to search, or you use the recursive search, it will print out the name of matching file at the start of the line.

Comment: +1 for recommending Ack. After all, it's http://betterthangrep.com

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is option `-H` of `grep` which shows the matching filename together with the match. You can also add `-r` to search a directory recursively. I.e.

```
$ grep -r -H "tanguay.info" /etc/httpd/conf/lxadmin/
```

Answer (score 2):

[find](http://www.liamdelahunty.com/tips/linux_find_string_files.php)

find . | xargs grep 'string' -sl

The -s is for summary and won't display warning messages such as grep: ./directory-name: Is a directory

The -l is for list, so we get just the filename and not all instances of the match displayed in the results.

Comment: -1 First of all, never use find and xargs without using -print0 with find and -0 with xargs, or files with spaces will cause you problems. Secondly, you've just reimplemented "grep -r", badly. Thirdly, -s is "suppress error messages", not "summary"

Answer (score 2):

```
# cd /directory/of/files/
# grep -A 5 -B 5 'keywords' *
```

show 5 lines before and 3 lines after so that you can see the context of the keywords

makes all the difference in understanding how the keywords are used in the file

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Rl "tanguay.info" /etc/httpd/conf/lxadmin/
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows systems:

```
type *.* | find "<string>"
```

The quotes must be in there, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use backquote to find only in files. [ **`** -> key left to Number 1 key above to Tab key]

grep -wn  "tanguay.info"  `find /etc/httpd/conf/lxadmin/ -iname "*.conf"`

The above code will first get the *.conf files and then search the "tanguay.info" among the result.

Run the above command in a super user login to avoid permission problems.

Answer (score 0):

The solition below is very similar to Izzy's response above but offers a little more flexibility. I find it very useful when I need to do a little more than xargs will allow (especially on older SunOS systems where `grep -r` or `rgrep` is not available)

```
find . -name "*.conf" -exec grep -l tanguay.info {} \;
```

Quite simply, you are finding all the *.conf files and executing a grep on each result that is found. The `\;` completes the -exec portion of the command.